# Doxyclean Error

Tags: doxygen

I'm trying to run doxyclean but can't get it to work, any help would be appreciated...

I'm running from terminal :

```
./doxyclean.py --input=./xml/ --output=./clean/ --name="MyProject" --phone -v
```

I have my doxygen xml in the folder xml, in the same directory as doxyclean.py

The result is :

```
Checking arguments
Cleaning XML files:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./doxyclean.py", line 1220, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "./doxyclean.py", line 1171, in main
    cleanXML(filePath, xmlOutputDirectory)
  File "./doxyclean.py", line 93, in cleanXML
    if not fileIsDocumented(filePath):
  File "./doxyclean.py", line 62, in fileIsDocumented
    originaldoc = minidom.parse(filePath)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1918, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 924, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(fp)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 207, in parseFile
    parser.Parse(buffer, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 17, column 155
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you try other ways, my suggestions

1. use different version of doxyclean
2. change the arguments to different style, maybe give full paths to the folders.
   `./doxyclean.py -i Users/xxx/doxyclean/xml/ -o ./clean/ -p`
3. regenerate xml from doxygen

doxyclean works fine. I got this error too and I tried my suggestion 2 and it worked.

Comment: which os are u running this on ?